# Access Attachment field Add, update button disabled in Form

Tags: ms-access, attachment

I have a Form in Access table and an Attachment field and it is published in sharepoint. Attachement field is working fine in the table. But its disabled in the form.

When i Click the attachment button, window pops up but the add, update buttons are disabled ??

[image: Form Attachment Popup]

[image: Table Attachment Popup]

Comment: Have you done any research on how SharePoint handles Attachment field? Does this offer any insight https://dcsharepointchick.blogspot.com/2012/07/display-item-attachments-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: Its not about attachment in Sharepoint, its about MS Access Form, In MS Access Table i can add the attachment by clicking the attachment button, but the same is not working in Form field

Comment: I cannot replicate issue but I don't use SharePoint. If SharePoint is not issue, then why mention it? Appears to be a design problem, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I have disabled the button in script. Enabled it now

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is late to reply , but i have faced the same with my forms , i have foud out the reason for this , it is the record source , if you make the form source as sql you will face the problem of disabled buttons , you have to make the form tecord source is the table itself not a sql code .

[image]